# .NET FileSystemWatcher to detect NTFS security changes

Tags: c#, .net, security, ntfs, filesystemwatcher

The .NET FileSystemWatcher's Changed event [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed.aspx) says:

> The Changed event is raised when changes are made to the size, system attributes, last write time, last access time, or **security permissions** of a file or directory in the directory being monitored.

However, when I try to use this class to capture NTFS security changes to a directory or a file the Changed event never fires.

Is there some way of accomplishing this without polling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` does watch security permissions changes.
You need to include `NotifyFilters.Security` flag, when you set `FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter`.
I tried the code below, changed permissions for a file in `Temp` folder. The `Changed` event was triggered.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\Temp", "*.*");
    fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Security;
    fileSystemWatcher.Changed += fileSystemWatcher_Changed;
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    Thread.Sleep(-1);
}

private static void fileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed NotifyFilter.